# Prove inequality using AM-GM inequality.

Tags: inequality

$$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\geq \sqrt{a+b}$$ I know it is trivial to prove straight forward but I need to prove it using AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Why do you assume it can be done?

Comment: I don't know it for sure. This exercise in a math book an i assume that it can be done.

Comment: Please state the exercise exactly.

Comment: It's already stated. Prove the following ... using AM-GM inequality. That's it.

Comment: @Bakyr Even adding the harmonic mean inequality doesn't seem to help in this case. Were you *specifically* asked to prove this with the AM-GM inquality or is it only a personal quest?

Comment: You can delete comments, @Mick

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How can I do that (after 4 minutes)?

Comment: The delete comments "x" mark, when you hover over your comment, always works. @Mick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt a + \sqrt b
&= \frac{(\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt2 \sqrt[4]{ab}) +
          (\sqrt a + \sqrt b - \sqrt2 \sqrt[4]{ab})}{2} \\
&\ge \sqrt{\big(\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt2 \sqrt[4]{ab}\big)
          \big(\sqrt a + \sqrt b - \sqrt2 \sqrt[4]{ab}\big)} \\
&= \sqrt{\big(\sqrt a + \sqrt b\big)^2 - 2 \sqrt{ab}} \\
&= \sqrt{a+b}
\end{align*}
(To apply AM/GM thus requires $\sqrt a + \sqrt b \ge \sqrt2\sqrt[4]{ab}$; happily, $\sqrt a + \sqrt b \ge 2\sqrt[4]{ab}$, by AM/GM again.)